# Limiting Drag and Pinch Gestures - SwfiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The issue is user able to pinch and drag gestures in the canvas, user not able to move or zoom more than canvas sizes.

Canvas sizes and item sizes are changing.
I couldn't calculate the min and max values.

For example there is a image in canvas user can zoom but limit is the canvas size.
User can move image but limit is the canvas size.

Do you have a solution for to this problem, can you help me ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CanvasItemGesture<Content: View, Model: AddingToolModel>: View {
    @GestureState private var gesturePan: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var currentZoom = 1.0
    
    let content: Content
    @Binding var model: Model
    
    @State private var itemPosition = CGPoint(x: -50, y: -50)
    @State private var itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    @State private var rectSize: CGFloat = 393
    @State private var zoomValue: CGFloat = 0

    
    init(model: Binding<Model>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self._model = model
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            content
                .position(itemPosition)
                .frame(width: itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height)
                .gesture(panGesture.simultaneously(with: zoomGesture))
    }
    
    private var zoomGesture: some Gesture {
        MagnifyGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                
                let magnification = value.magnification
                if self.zoomValue <= magnification {
                    itemSize += CGSize(width: magnification,
                                       height: magnification)
                    self.zoomValue = magnification
                } else {
                    itemSize += CGSize(width: -magnification,
                                      height: -magnification)
                    self.zoomValue = magnification
                }
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                model.zoom += currentZoom
                currentZoom = 0
            }
    }
    
    private var panGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0,
                    coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged({ value in
                let height = (rectSize - itemSize.height)
                let width = (rectSize - itemSize.width)
                let limitedX = max(min(value.location.x, width), -itemSize.width)
                let limitedY = max(min(value.location.y, height), -itemSize.height)

                self.itemPosition = CGPoint(x: limitedX,
                                            y: limitedY)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.